# Text Justification in Rmarkdown word document

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

When I create the word document in Rmarkdown, text is always left-aligned:
[image]

Is it possible (and how) to justify the text in Rmarkdown?

Comment: I believe it is. See https://vimeo.com/110804387

Comment: Work like a charm, even in LibreOffice. Thanks for your great work!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A template (i.e., like a custom style sheet) can be created in Word (or LibreOffice / OpenOffice), containing whatever page formatting and document styles you wish, and referenced from the rmarkdown file, i.e.,

```
---
title: "My Document"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: mystyles.docx
---
...rest of your rmarkdown here...
```

See:

- https://vimeo.com/110804387
- http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html
- http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html