# Right justify a single line of text in RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I know its possible to change text justification and other setting when RMarkdown generates Word documents using a template.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238643/text-justification-in-rmarkdown-word-document).

Is it possible to change the justification of a single line?

For example, text that looks like

```
  Some normal left justified text

                                                           some right justified text

  Some more left justified text
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238643/text-justification-in-rmarkdown-word-document) will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flushright works if your output format is .pdf but not for .html or word document.

```
Some normal left justified text

\begin{flushright}

some right justified text

\end{flushright}

Some normal left justified text
```

It seems to be important to leave the lines in between empty.