# How to justify the text to both sides when knitting html in rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown

```
---
title: '1'
author: "A"
date: "April 4, 2017"
output: html_document
---

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Figure 3 includes the residual plot and QQ-plot. The residual plot have no obvious pattern: the expect value of residuals is close to 0 and the variances are approximately equal. The QQ-plot shows the standardized residuals are close to the theoretical quantiles. Thus, **the residuals are normally distributed and homoscedastic, and the assumption of the liner model is satisfied**. The VIF values for each variable in the best model is small, indicating **there are no obvious multicolinearity**.
```

Use the above code for example, as it shows in the picture, the second line and third line are aligned to the left by default.

[image]

What should I do if I want to align to **both sides**? (Notice: not align to the center!)

[Text Justification in Rmarkdown word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238643/text-justification-in-rmarkdown-word-document) gives the solution for word output case, but I haven't found a good reference for html case.

Comment: please share html

Answer (score 44):

Just overwrite the alignment right after the YAML:

```
---
title: '1'
author: "A"
date: "April 4, 2017"
output: html_document
---

<style>
body {
text-align: justify}
</style>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Figure 3 includes the residual plot and QQ-plot. The residual plot have no obvious pattern: the expect value of residuals is close to 0 and the variances are approximately equal. The QQ-plot shows the standardized residuals are close to the theoretical quantiles. Thus, **the residuals are normally distributed and homoscedastic, and the assumption of the liner model is satisfied**. The VIF values for each variable in the best model is small, indicating **there are no obvious multicolinearity**.
```

Credits to Guilherme Parreira, [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1410023525939155/permalink/1885895888351914/)