# How to justify (to both sides) text in R Markdown when knitting in pdf output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have looked for ways to control the alignment of the text, however I could not find anything for PDF outputs.

There is an existing answer, but related to HTML output only: [How to justify the text to both sides when knitting html in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222169/how-to-justify-the-text-to-both-sides-when-knitting-html-in-rmarkdown).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

R Markdown should default to using justified text. However, if you only want to export to PDF, we can directly use LaTeX commands within the document.using the standard arguments `\centering` `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`, as explained [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Text_alignment#Fully_justified_text).

Here is a minimal example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
devtools::install_github("coolbutuseless/lipsum")
library(lipsum)
```

**Default**

`r lipsum[1]`

\centering

**Centered Text**

`r lipsum[1]`

\raggedright

**Ragged Right**

`r lipsum[1]`

\raggedleft

**Ragged Left**

`r lipsum[1]`
````

[image]

If you want to revert to justified text, you can use the `ragged2e` LaTeX package. You will need to load this within the YAML by adding:

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
---

\raggedleft

**Ragged Left**

`r lipsum[1]`



\justifying

**Revert to Justified**

`r lipsum[1]`
```

## Edit

If you are using the `papaja` template you need to include all the YAML. Not providing an author, shorttitle or another other field will cause it to crash.

````
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"
  - name          : "Ernst-August Doelle"
    affiliation   : "1,2"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Wilhelm-Wundt-University"
  - id            : "2"
    institution   : "Konstanz Business School"

author_note: |
  Add complete departmental affiliations for each author here. Each new line herein must be indented, like this line.

  Enter author note here.

abstract: |
  Enter abstract here. Each new line herein must be indented, like this line.
  
keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]

figsintext        : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
lineno            : yes
mask              : no

class             : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
---

```{r load_packages, include = FALSE}

library(lipsum)
```
\justifying

**Default**

`r lipsum[1]`
````

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to justify only chunks and outputs, but not text?

Comment: I'm not immediately sure @ForEverNewbie. You may want to open a new question this :)

Comment: You should use `\justifying` instead of `\justify`. The later kinda works by accident, but causes a lot of strange problems, because it is actually an environment and not a macro.